# ef core 1.1 Autogenerated column using ValueGeneratedOnAdd

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

Using **EfCore 1.1**, I am trying to have a autogenerated column using ValueGeneratedOnAdd. The problem is i am always getting value as "0". Do i have to manually do anything with the database table ?

Here is my model

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

   // This needs to be auto generated
    public Int32 ContactIndex { get; set; } 

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } 
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my OnModelCreating looks like

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .Property(c => c.ContactIndex)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
          // I tried following as well but it did't work
           // .HasDefaultValueSql("IDENTITY(int, 1,1)");
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using migrations or trying to map to existing table? And want/have 2 identity columns `Id` and `ContactIndex`?

Comment: Yea i used migrations to add new column "ContactIndex". The tables primary key is a GUID. This column "ContactIndex" is a number column but i need to have number autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured how to do it, but i really wanted to do that without using any annotations, and i still cannot figure out how to do it without annotations on model. So here is my solution.

You need to annotate your filed in the model like following

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 ContactIndex { get; set; } 

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; } 
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
}
```

and add OnModelCreating in your context class. This will tell entity framework to ignore the column while adding or updating records. Make sure you calling method .ValueGeneratedAddOrUpdate( ). If you use only .ValueGeneratedAdd( ) you will get errors while making updates.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
        .Property(c => c.ContactIndex)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
    ;
}
```

Generate and run your migrations and your migrations should include "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn"

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        name: "ContactIndex",
        table: "Contact",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: 0)
        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
}
```